# Why would a service's onUnbind method not execute on a call to unbindService from the only connected client in Android?

Tags: android, service

I am working on an application which will poll and record data from a remote device even when the application that launched it isn't in the foreground.  In order to do this I created a service which is launched by my main app once the user has adjusted a few settings.  Currently I am able to start the service from my app and pass configuration data to it through the intent.  It is my understanding that onUnbind only runs when all clients have disconnected.  I am only connecting a single client to the service so I would expect this method to fire as soon as I command my app to unbind.

### Problem

After originally binding to the service, if I later try to unbind the onUnbind function doesn't execute.  Similarly, if I try to bind to it again neither onBind nor onRebind execute.  I've tried printing to the log and toaster notifications to indicate the respective functions are being called.  I get no feedback in either case.  This has me quite convinced there is something wrong with my interface to the service.

I'm sure these issues are related but I'm new to Android Services and have been unable to locate a section of the docs which explains the problem.  Any direction as to what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful.  Code is included below, thanks!

#### Activity Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Boolean isBound = false;

    private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    Button rec_button;
    TextView dmr_fname;
    TextView dmr_status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Remove this button...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        rec_button = findViewById(R.id.rec_button);
        rec_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Recorder started (not really)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        doUnBind();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            // Open settings activity
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_dmr) {
            // TODO: Open a file dialog so user can select DMR to parse
            Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //fileintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            fileintent.setType("text/*");
            try {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileintent, "Open CSV"), PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_quitservice) {
            try {
                doUnBind();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error encountered unbinding from DMR service: "+e);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        dmr_fname = findViewById(R.id.DMR_filename);
        dmr_status = findViewById(R.id.DMR_status);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                    // TODO: Add a function here to try two different file paths (one for SD, one internal, and return the proper one
                    // For now, just assume it's internal downloads
                    Log.d(TAG,"Path Segments: "+data.getData().getPathSegments());
                    FilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+FilePath.split(":")[1];
                    dmr_fname.setText(FilePath);
                    dmr_status.setText("Parsing...");
                    List<DMR_Data_Item> DMR_List = parseDMR(FilePath);
                    dmr_status.setText("Setting up service...");
                    doBind(DMR_List);
                    if (dmrConnection != null) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"dmrConnection bound successfully!");
                    }
                    dmr_status.setText("Ready!");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    private ArrayList<DMR_Data_Item> parseDMR(String file) {
        ArrayList<DMR_Data_Item> out_data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Attempting to open "+file);

            /* TODO: Someday request permissions so we can target SDK versions above 23, sample code is below:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
            }*/

            FileReader input = new FileReader(new File(file));

            //InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(input);
            String inString;

            while ((inString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split up the line and put it into the array if it matches the format
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Line from file: "+inString);
                    String[] row_data = inString.split(",");
                    out_data.add(new DMR_Data_Item(row_data[0], row_data[2], Integer.parseInt(row_data[4]),row_data[5].charAt(0),row_data[9]));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing the DMR.. Perhaps the header was not removed? "+e);
                }
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception encountered: " + e.toString());
        }
        return out_data;
    }

    private ServiceConnection dmrConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Connected to DMRService");

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Disconnected from DMRService");
        }
    };

    void doBind(List<DMR_Data_Item> DMR_List) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DMRService.class);
        for (int i=0; i<DMR_List.size();i++) {
            intent.putExtra("DMR_List["+i+"]",DMR_List.get(i));
        }
        bindService(intent,dmrConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        isBound = true;
    }

    void doUnBind() {
        if (isBound) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Requesting unbind from DMRService");
            unbindService(dmrConnection);
            isBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Service Code:

```
public class DMRService extends Service {

    String TAG = "DMRService";
    IBinder mBind;
    boolean writing = false;
    long write_timeout = -1;
    Long oldest_arr[];
    ArrayList<DMR_Data_Item> DMR_List = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<My_Measurement>> data_array = new ArrayList<>();
    int idx = 0;
    int MEMORY = 60;    // Number of seconds of data to store before and after a trigger

    public DMRService() {
        Log.v(TAG,"DMR Service is running");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG,"Running onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startID);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service binding", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG,"Bind requested from intent "+intent);
        // Get DMR list from intent
        try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                    DMR_List.add((DMR_Data_Item) bundle.get(key));
                    Log.v(TAG,"New DMR Item: "+DMR_List.get(DMR_List.size()-1).getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error encountered: "+e);
            return null;
        }

        // Initialize oldest array
        oldest_arr = new Long[DMR_List.size()];
        Arrays.fill(oldest_arr,Long.valueOf(0));

        // Make lists for storing data within the data array (one per DMR variable)
        for (int i=0; i<DMR_List.size();i++) {
            data_array.add(new ArrayList<My_Measurement>());
        }

        // Make a list to store the lists of data items

        // Create a vehicle manager instance and CAN listener
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.v(TAG, "Finished binding! Data Array Size: "+data_array.size()+" Oldest Array Length: "+oldest_arr.length);
        return mBind;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service rebound", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service unBinding", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG,"Unbind requested by intent "+intent);
        unbindService(mConnection);
        // Reset all variables and lists
        writing = false;
        write_timeout = -1;
        Long oldest_arr[];
        DMR_List = new ArrayList<>();
        data_array = new ArrayList<>();
        idx = 0;

        return false;   // Not rebind-able
    }
}
```

Comment: why calling `bindService` to self inside `onBind`? `onBind` is called with `Intent intent` and you use the same `Intent` when calling `bindService`... why?

Comment: The service bind inside the onbind method is binding to another service my service gets data from. I left those portions of the code out of my snippet to make it shorter here.

Comment: so first try without that second `bindService` and check if `onUnbind` is called or not

Comment: Thank you!  Using a new intent for the `bindService` call in `onBind` resolved the issue!